# Generating PostgreSQL test data with relationships?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to generate 4 tables:

- customers
- subscriptions (references customersid and plans.id)
- plans
- invoices (each invoice references a subscription and a customer)

How can I write an INSERT query where I can insert an invoice, and randomly generate the subscription_id by pulling in all id's from subs and selecting one, then pull in the appropriate customer_id of that subscription for that invoice row?

Comment: Invoices shouldn't reference customer if it already references a subscription. That would be a denormalized schema, which increases your chances of creating conflicting data. You should `JOIN` invoice to subscription to get the related customer ID.

Comment: OK thanks but my question is about selecting data from other tables within an INSERT query. All my queries work fine, I just need to generate invoice test data with SQL which is really tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You can search and find Northwind sample data for PostgreSQL on the internet. Northwind model have tables that matches your model. In northwind sample you can rename and use:

Customers,
Employees (Plans),
Orders (Subscriptions),
OrderDetails (Invoices)

Invoices should only reference to Subscriptions (and it already references to Customers).